# reset auto increment id after deletion of last row

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I made a table in a mysql database for testing purposes. 
The id is auto incremented. After doing this(not together)

```
delete from test where id=4;
alter table test auto_increment = 4;
insert into test(nume) values('dan');
```

It does not give any errors. But the last id is 5, not 4. Should not this be working?

Comment: well, i used another option : ALTER TABLE test DROP `id`;
ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE test ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;

Answer (score 2):

After delete write this query

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Shouldn't ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = x+1, where x is the biggest id (SELECT MAX(id) from tablename) ?

Comment: no, it doesn't. Does it have something to do with the fact that it is innodb?

Answer (score 0):

Question yourself, whether you need to alter the primary key. In most legitimate cases - no.

This will partially work, once you insert a row, the ID will be 4, but auto_increment will change to 5.

As a result, next row insertion will give you a primary key duplication error.

Comment: Well, after I delete the last row, select max(id) from test equals 3, so I alter auto_increment to 3+1. Though the next is 5, not 4..

Comment: Oww interesting, I must have misunderstood you. I though "last is 5" - there is another row with ID 5. In that case, could you set auto_increment to max(id) rather than max(id) + 1 and see how works out?

Comment: no, that doesn't work either. there must be a simple explanation, but i cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This whole procedure has only use in case you do delete the record with the highest id. 
Should you delete where id=2, you cannot change the autoincrement id. For whatever reason you do not like to get a gap in the id line at id=4, in case of deleting id =2 there will be a gap. So why mess with the ids when after adding a new record id =5 you would have the same kind of gap.

But what about racing conditions. You delete record id=4. two millisec later I add a record, getting id=5. What will happen to the auto increment id?

What legit reason is there for avoiding these gaps?